# Скрипт для добавления строк во всех вкладках (googlesheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть googlesheet с 4 схожими вкладками (на каждой, одинаковый шаблон таблиц, но разные данные) и одна вкладка со списком названий 4х первых вкладок. Пример: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xdws6Vr6YVXuj19mvpOvkpJokOfY2T7Sh1aMpous_Xw/edit#gid=0

Что делает скрипт: заходит в каждую вкладку и добавляет определенное количество строк, копируя дату с предыдущей строки, увеличивая её на месяц.
Куда вставлять строку, определяется местом где написано слово "Picture"

В чем возникла проблема:
вставка строк происходит только для одной ячейки на листе где встречается Picture. Если Picture встречается 3 раза например, то строки вставятся только в одном месте.

Как сделать чтобы строки вставлялись во всех местах на листе где есть Picture?

Код (благодарности Ihor Husar за помощь и понимание):

```
function loop(howMany){
  if(!howMany){howMany = 2;};
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();//returns an array of all sheets
  //this is just a different way of looping through the sheets
  for (var sheetId = 0; sheetId<sheets.length; sheetId++){
    if(sheets[sheetId].getSheetName() != "All_base"){
      var data = sheets[sheetId].getDataRange().getValues();
      var insertAfter = 6;
      for(var i = 5; i<data.length; i++){
        if(data[i][0] == "Picture"){
          insertAfter = i-1; //it is actually -2, but since i starts from 0, it is already smaller by 1;
          //actual row of Picture cell is i+1, and 2 cells up is i+1-2 = i-1
        };
      };
      sheets[sheetId].insertRowsAfter(insertAfter, howMany);
      //At this point we inserted rows
      var lastDate = sheets[sheetId].getRange(insertAfter,1).getCell(1,1).getValue();//the last specified date as a Date object
      for(var i=0; i<howMany; i++){
        var newDate = new Date(lastDate.getTime());
        newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth()+1+i);//automatically will increase year if the next month is in the next year.
        sheets[sheetId].getRange(insertAfter+1+i,1).getCell(1,1).setValue(newDate);
      };
    };
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Этот цикл написан неверно:

```
for(var i = 5; i<data.length; i++){
  if(data[i][0] == "Picture"){
    insertAfter = i-1;
  };
};
sheets[sheetId].insertRowsAfter(insertAfter, howMany);
```

В случае обнаружения "Picture" изменяется значение insertAfter... и ничего больше не происходит. А нужно было вставить строки, именно внутри цикла а не после него.

Вот подправленный вариант:

```
for (var i = 5; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i][0] == "Picture") {
    insertAfter = i-1;
    sheets[sheetId].insertRowsAfter(insertAfter, howMany);
  }
}
```

Однако есть ещё одна проблема: процесс вставки изменяет номера последующих строк, что приводит к путанице. Если требуется вставить несколько строк в разных местах, нужно вставлять начиная снизу, а не сверху. То есть, изменить цикл с `for(var i = 5; i<data.length; i++)` на `for(var i = data.length-1; i>=5; i--)`:

```
for (var i = data.length-1; i >= 5; i--) {
  if (data[i][0] == "Picture") {
    insertAfter = i-1;
    sheets[sheetId].insertRowsAfter(insertAfter, howMany);
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Но проблема всё равно осталась. Строки добавляется, но они пустые т.е. ячейки с последующими месяцами вставляются только в одном месте, в другом месте (где встречается picture) вставляются пустые строки. Также, поиск значения "picture" проихсодит только в первом столбце; если вставить его в другое место таблицы, то оно его на находит..

Comment: Поиск только в первом столбце, потому что так написано: `if (data[i][0] == "Picture")`. Чтобы искать везде, нужно это заменить на `if (data[i].indexOf("Picture") != -1)`

Comment: Круто, еще раз благодарю) Осталось только решить момент со вставкой ячеек с датой (сейчас вставляется только в одном месте, в остальных местах добавляются пустые строки). Попробовал перенести блок с  `var lastDate` в тот же цикл куда перенесли вставку строк, но появлется ошибка: "TypeError: Не удается обнаружить функцию getTime в объекте "